# JRuby limited openssl loaded - how to eliminate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, openssl, installation

What could be done to deprecate the message when running each JRuby project?

```
JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
```

the jruby-openssl gem IS installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you are using bundler, i think that you need to add jruby-openssl to your Gemfile, cause otherwise the gem is not "visible".

```
gem "jruby-openssl", :platforms => :jruby
```